# Discrepancy in behavior between Array.fill and [...]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I hit a weird behavior when trying to generate and use symetrically generated 2D Matrices in Node/Chrome. The generating method is shown below.

```
const test=(f) => {
    // Omitted
    // Could provide full source if needed but it's not small
}
const gen=(boxSize)=>{
    const boardSize = boxSize ** 2;
    return new Array(boardSize).fill(new Array(boardSize).fill(0));
}

console.log(gen(2)); // [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
test(gen(2)); // fails
test(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gen(2)))); // passes
test([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]); // passes
```

Why do I get this inconsistent(?!) behavior between they ways of initializing the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the issue here stems from the fact that all the rows of `gen(2)` are a reference to the same array. So modifying any row will in fact modify every row; no doubt this is not the behavior you want.

This is because the `Array.fill` method will use *exactly the same thing* for each element of the filled array. Note that the thing you're filling with is a reference to another array, thus each element will be a reference to that same array.

To fix this, I would recommend using `.map` on top of `.fill`:

```
return new Array(boardSize).fill().map(() => new Array(boardSize).fill(0))
```

or perhaps use `Array.from`:

```
return Array.from({length: boardSize}, () => new Array(boardSize).fill(0))
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks, I totally missed that point... In hindsight its totally obvious...